# foreach item in an array find largest record using mongodbcsharp driver

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose there is an document like:

```
{
    "_id": "1cf2080c-ce9a-367b-93ba-dbf7b2bf8a2c",
    "template_id" : "1cf2080c-ce9a-367b-93ba-dbf7b2bf8a2c",
    "some_value" : 12
}
```

mapping to a class as `Template`, and given a templateid array `array_id = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]`

**question:** how can I get a `Template` List using mongodb C# driver2.1 up, which each item in list have largest `some_value` ?

for example there is a collection:

```
{"_id": "1", "template_id": "aa", "some_value":1}

{"_id": "2", "template_id": "aa", "some_value":2}

{"_id": "3", "template_id": "aa", "some_value":3}

{"_id": "4", "template_id": "bb", "some_value":4}

{"_id": "5", "template_id": "bb", "some_value":5}
```

and a `template_id_array = ["aa", "bb"]`

expect result is:

```
{"_id": "3", "template_id": "aa", "some_value":3}

{"_id": "5", "template_id": "bb", "some_value":5}
```

I think it would be some "aggregate" or "map-reduce" like procedure, first match result and then group by template id and then find max somevalue for each group.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but should work with some probable modifications

```
var result = new List<Template>();
foreach (var element in template_id_array)
{
    var filter = builder.Eq("TemplateId", element);
    var doc = await collection.Find(filter)
    .SortByDescending(x => x.SomeValue)
    .Limit(1)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    result.Add(doc);
}
```

Then you can serialize it to the final form:

```
var expectedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Comment: sorry for not make my point clear, actually i would like to use some mongodb "sql like" query in just one line, not linq